# How to get an attribut with HTML::TreeBuilder

Tags: html, perl, parsing, custom-attributes

I try to extract the JSon inside the body Tag of a Jamendo Site:

```
<body id="album-home" data-tracksMgr='{...}'>
```

I have studied HTML::Element and HTML::Tree::Scanning but I had no luck. If I dump the tree I see `data-tracksMgr`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use HTML::TreeBuilder;
use YAML::Any qw'DumpFile LoadFile';
my $url = 'http://www.jamendo.com/de/list/a116765';
my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_url( $url );
my @data = $tree->attr_get_i("data-tracksMgr");
DumpFile('test.yaml', @data);
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What does the HTML look like?  And do you get any errors or other output?

Comment: you can look at the HTML on the Website - I don't get any error... I don't get anything back

Comment: That URL returns a 301. Try accessing that URL instead.

Comment: What happens if you use $data instead of @data.  $data will shift of the first element in that attr_get_i array it returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another method is to use [`Mojo::UserAgent`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo%3a%3aUserAgent) and [`Mojo::DOM`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo%3a%3aDOM) to both get the webpage and retrieve the attribute.  Note, that the url that you specified actually redirects to another location, so it's necessary to say to follow redirects:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Mojo::UserAgent;
use YAML::Any qw(DumpFile LoadFile);

my $url = 'http://www.jamendo.com/de/list/a116765';
#my $url = 'http://www.jamendo.com/de/list/a116765/after-the-rain';  # Redirects to this URL

my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new(max_redirects => 5);
my $dom = $ua->get($url)->res->dom;

my $data = $dom->find('body')->attr('data-tracksmgr');

DumpFile('test.yaml', "$data");
```

Just like with `HTML::TreeBuilder`, all attributes are lowercase.

Both of these modules can be installed with [`Mojolicious`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious) and there is a helpful 8 minute introduction to the UA and Dom selector at [`Mojocast Episode 5`](http://mojocasts.com/e5)

Comment: Thanks, that's easier and more intuitiv then HTML::TreeBuilder. Your Expanation has helped also a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is.  You need to get a sub element, since the attr_get_i returns the attributes moving up the hierarchy.  Also, the data-tracksMgr was changed to all lowercase in the DataDump I used, so searching for that attribute required a lowercase M.

```
my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_url( $url );
my $div = $tree->find_by_tag_name('div');
my $data = $div->attr_get_i("data-tracksmgr");
DumpFile('test.yaml', $data);
```

The div is arbitrary, since all the div's are children of the body tag, so I just grab the first one by using scalar context.

Comment: thanks, now I understand TreeBuilder a bit better :)